# How to enable Brotli compression in Nginx and Docker for Angular App

Tags: angular, linux, docker, nginx, brotli

For Docker based Angular application I want to enable Brotli compression on Nginx for this I have added below commands to `Dockerfile` and turned brotli on in `nginx/default.conf` file.

nginx/default.conf:

```
server {
    brotli on;
    brotli_static on;

    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build-env
WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json .

RUN npm install

ADD . .

RUN npm run build:prod

FROM nginx:alpine

RUN apk add nginx-mod-http-brotli

RUN sed -i '1i load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN sed -i '1i load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build-env /app/dist/ng-docker-mark-2 /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 8080
```

Here, I have added `nginx:alpine` after that installing `nginx-mod-http-brotli` which is an Apline Linux Package [nginx-mod-http-brotli](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nginx-mod-http-brotli&branch=v3.18&repo=&arch=&maintainer=). Later adding `load_module` on top of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

Now, the build command runs without any error:

```
docker build -t ng-docker:mark-3 .
```

But when I try to create and run the container get below error:

```
docker run -p 4300:80 --name ng-docker-mark-3-container-1 ng-docker:mark-3
```

Error:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/05/12 14:34:22 [emerg] 1#1: module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so" version 1022001 instead of 1023004 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so" version 1022001 instead of 1023004 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

Mainly it talks about this:

```
version 1022001 instead of 1023004
```

I have checked the container through Windows Docker Desktop app and I can see the modules got installed correctly, and its appearing in `world` file:

/etc/apk/world:

```
alpine-baselayout
alpine-keys
apk-tools
busybox
ca-certificates
curl
libc-utils
libintl
musl
nginx=1.23.4-r1
nginx-mod-http-brotli
nginx-module-geoip=1.23.4-r1
nginx-module-image-filter=1.23.4-r1
nginx-module-njs=1.23.4.0.7.11-r1
nginx-module-xslt=1.23.4-r1
tzdata
```

[image: world file]

Also, modules are appearing in the `/usr/lib/nginx/modules` folder too:

[image: modules folder]

What I tried already:

- If I remove the `load_module` syntax from top of the
  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file then it gives error on `brotli on` this
  line of `nginx/default.conf` file.
- I have also tried the `apt` approach where I have used the `nginx:latest` distribution but there I got package not found issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struggled with this too. It is a mismatch between the compiled version of nginx and the module. The answer is to fetch them from the same source. So instead of using `nginx:alpine`, just use `alpine`

### Dockerfile

```
# Build container
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

# Make sure we got brotli
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --upgrade brotli
WORKDIR /usr
COPY package*.json ./
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
RUN cd /usr/dist && find . -type f -exec brotli {} \;

# Actual runtime container
FROM alpine
RUN apk add brotli nginx nginx-mod-http-brotli

# Minimal config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf

# Actual data
COPY --from=builder /usr/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 80
```

Note: I only use brotli static since I created `.br` files in the build step.

### default.conf

```
access_log /dev/stdout;
error_log /dev/stdout info;

server {

    brotli_static on;

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # Everything is a 404
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # You may need this to prevent return 404 recursion.
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

You might want to play with more nginx settings.

Comment: Thanks @stwissel, this worked very fine! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and in my case the solution was to create the folder `modules-enabled` and make a symlink to the broetli module. For some reason if you install broetli in alpine it creates just a folder `/etc/nginx/modules` without linking it to the `modules-enabled`. Only the latter one is automatically loaded on nginx runtime (if specified in your `nginx.conf`)

Answer (score 0):

As per @stwissel provided answer, I have done below changes in my Dockerfile and nginx.conf

Dockerfile:

```
# Build container
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app

# Make sure we got brotli
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --upgrade brotli

# NPM install and build
ADD package.json .
RUN npm install
ADD . .
RUN npm run build:prod

RUN cd /app/dist && find . -type f -exec brotli {} \;

# Actual runtime container
FROM alpine
RUN apk add brotli nginx nginx-mod-http-brotli

# Minimal config
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf

# Actual data
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ng-docker-mark-4 /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
    brotli on;
    brotli_static on;
    brotli_comp_level 6;
    brotli_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Here, is the article of the same for further reading:
[Brotli Dockerized Angular App with Nginx - NgDocker](https://codeomelet.com/posts/brotli-dockerized-angular-app-with-nginx-ngdocker)